# null is not an object evaluating this.state.touppercase() in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to change value in textfiled to uppercase. While doing this, I am getting the following error :

```
null is not an object evaluating this.state.touppercase()
```

Please help me with this issue, I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

```
<Text style={_fs.row_container_module_value}>{this.state.bayNum.toUpperCase()}</Text>
```

Please find error image below ..if image is not visible plz clicl on link

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAc7Q.png)

Comment: Image not related to the upperCase issue!

Comment: Well, so bayNum is null at first render so you want to check if bayNum exist do ur job